# Mouse disappears while using Barrier (client PopOs)

Tags: networking, mouse, vmware, synergy

I'm running Pop-os 22.04 LTS on my laptop and Windows 11 on my computer and I've been trying to set up mouse and keyboard share with Barrier (my Windows PC as a server and my POP OS laptop as a Client). The connection works fine, but the mouse becomes invisible when I enter the popos screen (I'm sure it works cause if I use popos as server then everything is okay). I tried using enabling/disabling Xorg by editing gdm3 file but it can't solve the issue. Is this a known issue and if yes, does anyone know how to fix it?

(Barrier 2.3.3 on windows as a server works just fine, but if I install 2.4 on windows then this problem arises?

Comment: Looks like it might be a bug. You should report it to the devs.